# How can I know when my UITextView is scrolled?

Tags: ipad

I'm wondering if it's possible to know when a user is scrolling a `UITextView`. If it is, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `UITextView` is inherited from `UIScrollView`, so your delegate will be able to respond to events such as `scrollViewDidScroll:` and `scrollViewDidZoom:`. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) for the full list.